# Rename triple nested lists in r

Tags: r

How do I change the names of the triple nested lists across all nested lists?

Here is a triple nested list:

```
list.A <- list(a = c(1,2,5,6), b = c(2,4,6,5), c = c(2,4,2,5))
list.B <- list(a = c(7,7,7,7), b = c(8,8,8,8), c = c(9,9,9,9))
weights <- list(list.A, list.B)
names(weights) <- c("list.A", "list.B")

list.A <- list(a = c(2,2,2,2), b = c(3,3,3,3), c = c(4,4,4,4))
list.B <- list(a = c(5,5,5,5), b = c(6,6,6,6), c = c(7,7,7,7))
scores <- list(list.A, list.B)
names(scores) <- c("list.A", "list.B")

megalist <- list(weights, scores)
names(megalist) <- c("weights", "scores")
megalist

> megalist
$weights
$weights$list.A
$weights$list.A$a
[1] 1 2 5 6

$weights$list.A$b
[1] 2 4 6 5

$weights$list.A$c
[1] 2 4 2 5


$weights$list.B
$weights$list.B$a
[1] 7 7 7 7

$weights$list.B$b
[1] 8 8 8 8

$weights$list.B$c
[1] 9 9 9 9



$scores
$scores$list.A
$scores$list.A$a
[1] 2 2 2 2

$scores$list.A$b
[1] 3 3 3 3

$scores$list.A$c
[1] 4 4 4 4


$scores$list.B
$scores$list.B$a
[1] 5 5 5 5

$scores$list.B$b
[1] 6 6 6 6

$scores$list.B$c
[1] 7 7 7 7
```

I would like to change the names of the 3 lists IN `list.A`, which is in both `weights` and `scores`.

To make things more complicated, I would like to change the names of the 3 lists in `list.A` to the `rownames` of `mydf`.

Here is mydf:

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(c(12, 34, 72))
rownames(mydf) <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana")
colnames(mydf) <- "variable"

> mydf
    
variable
<dbl>
            
Apple   12          
Orange  34          
Banana  72
```

The result should look like this:

```
> desired.output
$weights
$weights$list.A
$weights$list.A$Apple
[1] 1 2 5 6

$weights$list.A$Orange
[1] 2 4 6 5

$weights$list.A$Banana
[1] 2 4 2 5


$weights$list.B
$weights$list.B$a
[1] 7 7 7 7

$weights$list.B$b
[1] 8 8 8 8

$weights$list.B$c
[1] 9 9 9 9



$scores
$scores$list.A
$scores$list.A$Apple
[1] 2 2 2 2

$scores$list.A$Orange
[1] 3 3 3 3

$scores$list.A$Banana
[1] 4 4 4 4


$scores$list.B
$scores$list.B$a
[1] 5 5 5 5

$scores$list.B$b
[1] 6 6 6 6

$scores$list.B$c
[1] 7 7 7 7
```

I can select the list, but I cannot figure out how to perform an action on the list:
`lapply(megalist,'[[',"list.A")`

I have tried:

```
names(megalist[[2]]$"list.A") <- rownames(mydf)
```

which only works on the second list `scores` and not on `list.A` contained within `weights`.

It does not work within both `weights` and `scores` lists for `list.A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.
For each member of `megalist` assign `new` to its `names` attribute.

```
lapply(megalist, \(x, new) {
  names(x[["list.A"]]) <- new
  x
}, new = row.names(mydf))
```

Comment: What is the \ doing in the code? I cannot get R to stop marking that as an unexpected input.

Comment: @simpson change \ with `function`.

Comment: @simpson ```\``` are the new lambda functions introduced in R 4.1. Change to `function` and it will work. Time to update R?

Comment: @RuiBarradas My R version is 4.2.1 but I guess my brain is still not updated. Changing the \ to function worked for me.